# Awk - find the minimum in a given row

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file organized in rows and columns. I want to find the minimum
in a given row, for example row number 4, and then transfer the corresponding column number in a bash variable (lev).

However the small code I wrote is not working

```
    lev=`echo - |awk '{
    m=100; l=1;
    {If (NR==4)
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
    {
        if( $i <m)
        m=$i;
        l=i
    } 
    }
    print l 

    }' file.txt`
```

Comment: Why do you need `echo - |` ?

Comment: It would be good to share some [mcve] so that we can assist. I don't think that getting the minimum in a row should need so much code. Also, the fact that you are using `NR` instead of `NF` makes me think that this code is not really working.

Comment: @anubhava I want to transfer the awk result into the bash variable lev.

Comment: Then it would be: `lev=$(awk '{...}' file.txt)`

Comment: @fedorqui As far as I understand (I am not an expert) NR gives you the number of the current line. Do I need to put an input file example to make the example more clear?

Comment: @Salsiccio yes, NR holds the number of the current line. And yes, to make things easier to understand, if you want us to help you should provide some input data and desired output so that we can "play" with it.

Comment: Also, as @anubhava , `echo -` is useless here. `var=$(awk '...' file)` is more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your script.  Perhaps you can figure out using this sample.

```
$ lev=$(awk 'NR==4{min=99999; 
             for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                  if($i < min) {min=$i; ix=i} 
             print ix}' file.txt)
```